# Assigning List of Strings in BPEL

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

Is there a way to assign a list of strings from input variable to invoke input variable?The problem is that there are multiple inputs in my web service so i am not able to copy the wrapping element in input variable to wrapping variable in invoke variable.Will copy the snippet of the code here :

```
<assign name="Assign1">
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:dsaName"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/dsaName"/>
            </copy>
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:linesOfData"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/linesOfData"/>
            </copy>
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:description"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/description"/>
            </copy>
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:application"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/application"/>
            </copy>
        </assign>
```

The problem is that only one is of list type all others are of string type.The XML for this is:

```
<element name="process">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                     <element name="dsaName" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="linesOfData" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

                    <element name="description" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </sequence>
    </complexType>
        </element>
    <element name="processResponse">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="result" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Comment: @vanto can you have a look at this.You helped me with a similar situation last time around.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your schema, you can use `doXSLTransform` operation where `<xsl:for-each>` is used to read the list type (here it's `linesOfData`) and add each of those elements to `Invoke1_processList_InputVariable`.

Comment: :I tried Transformation and then i tested the transformation(which shows perfect transformation) but still the bpel shows fault that the method
(in the web service) does not receive any data.Am i making some mistake here?In additional info i removed the assign and used tranform.Is there a mistake in this approach.

Comment: :More info:The source variable is input variable and target variable is invoke_input variable.Have a look.